# How to change the style of parent div of stage canvas?

Tags: css, kineticjs

**kineticjs** generates a div container to wrap a stage canvas. But it sets this div's display attribute as `display:inline-block`.

I would like the canvas is displayed in full screen without scroll bar in browser. But with `display: inline-block`, there are always scroll bar displayed.

If I can set display as auto, the scroll bar will disappear.

Is there any way to set the css style for the div generated by **kineticjs**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a few weeks ago. I also didn't want the scrollbars to be visible, because my canvas is always scaling to full-screen. I worked this out by setting the complete html/body to `overflow:hidden;`

Complete CSS of my `html, body`:

```
html, body{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To set the div at full-screen you simply have to set its width and height to 100%:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And last but not least, set the width and height of your stage to:

```
width: window.innerWidth,
height: window.innerHeight
```

I hope this could somehow resolve your problem :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you. It would be awesome if you could consider marking it as answer ;)

Comment: Sure, I have made it as answer. :-)